# ConstraintLayout cuts off too long text in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to make a master-detail view and I have a ListView with items of following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/start_point"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_date_val" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_to_vall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/end_point"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_to"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_from_vall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/end_point"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_from"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_from_vall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_from_vall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/start_point"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_from"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_from"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_from" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/date"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_date_val"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date_val"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_from_vall"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

which produces:
[image]

and the text of two last lines of list item on right side is cut off. I would like line break if text is too long.

I tried `android:lines="4"`, `android:singleLine = "false"`

Is there a way to fix it in TextView without changing the whole layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> you need to change

1. Change right text view width with `0dp`. You are using `wrap_content` and because of that this issue generate.
2. Change top to bottom constraint to all right textview, because when text increase it will overlap in your constraint.

   [image]

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_date"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
       android:text="date"
       app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_date_val"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_date_val"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:gravity="start"
       android:text="date text date text date text date text date text date text date text date text"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_from_vall"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_from"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:text="start_point"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_date"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_from_vall" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_from_vall"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:gravity="start"
       android:text="start_point start_point start_point start_point start_point start_point start_point"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_date_val"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_from"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_date_val" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_to"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:text="end_point"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_from"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_from_vall" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_to_vall"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:baselineAligned="false"
       android:gravity="start"
       android:text="end_point end_point end_point end_point end_point end_point end_point"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_to"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_date_val"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_from_vall" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by:

1. Using a match constraints width of each `TextView` which is (`0dp`) instead of
   `wrap_content`
2. Add end constraint to the end of the parent
   `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`

So your layout would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/start_point"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_date_val" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_to_vall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/end_point"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_to"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_from_vall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/end_point"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_from"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_from_vall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_from_vall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/start_point"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_from"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_from"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_from" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="@string/date"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tv_date_val"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date_val"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_from_vall"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```